# cant print hist with months in R

Tags: r, date, time-series, histogram

I have a Date variable in my dataframe.

```
> str(gran$Date)
 Date[1:1368], format: "2014-11-06" "2014-11-05" "2014-11-04" "2014-11-03" "2014-11-02" "2014-11-01" "2014-10-31" ...
```

When I print histogram as:

```
hist(gran$Date, "month")
```

It doesn't show per month. It just shows per Year as displayed below...

[image]

in addition to this:
I have a logical variable like:

```
gran$neg_WS = gran$Act.Rep.WS < 0
```

I want to draw histogram where negative value occurs i.e.

```
plot(gran$Date[gran$neg_WS], "month")
```

I get the following error:

```
> plot(gran$Date[gran$neg_WS], "month")
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I don't believe it is correct as length is the same i.e. 1368 for both variables.

```
> length(gran$neg_WS)
[1] 1368
> length(gran$Date)
[1] 1368
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: Please provide a minimal dataset that can reproduce the error, see these tips for providing [a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `length(gran$Date[gran$neg_WS])`

Comment: length(gran$Date[gran$neg_WS]) = 227 I don't understand why :(

Comment: please clone the following repo: https://github.com/fahadshery/prod_analysis

Comment: example.csv is the output using dput() in the Data folder. Please use the Gran_VS_Portal_ANALYSIS.Rmd in the Analysis folder for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a `format` specifying how R should label the *time* axis. Here is an example

```
set.seed(21)
gran <- list(Date = sample(seq(Sys.Date(), by = "months", length.out = 30),
                           1368, replace = TRUE))

with(gran, hist(Date, breaks = "months", format = "%b %Y", las = 2))
```

Compare this with the default chosen by the heuristics in the `hist()` method

```
with(gran, hist(Date, breaks = "months", las = 2))
```

[image]

The error with `plot(gran$Date[gran$neg_WS], "month")` is simple user error:

- `gran$Date[gran$neg_WS]` is a vector of length 227 (if your comment is correct)
- `"month"` is a character vector of length 1

You asked `plot` to do something with these variables and clearly their lengths differ.

Your logical vector `neg_ws` must be of the same length as the data from which is was formed. It will be a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values depending on the data and the clause you used. To see how many are `TRUE`, use `sum()` on the vector, which uses the convention that `TRUE == 1`.

The idea is that you would use `neg_WS` to *index* your data object to give you just those dates when `neg_WS` was `TRUE`.

```
set.seed(65)
gran$neg_WS <- runif(1368) < 0.5 # example logical vector
with(gran, hist(Date[neg_WS], breaks = "months", format = "%b %Y", las = 2))
```

Note how we subset `Date` using the logical vector `neg_WS`. This can only work if `neg_WS` is the same length as the vector we are indexing or multiple copies are exactly that length.